# What Is The Meaning Of This JS DOM Code?

Tags: javascript, dom

I found this function to find the JS DOM methods. However, I couldn't understand the logic behind it.

```
for (var l in document.body){
  console.log("document."+l+":"+document.body[l]);
}
```

What does the var 1 mean? It seems, document.body is an array and we are iterating over the array. However, something seems strange. In the above code, when I insert spaces around "1" and ":" inside the for loop, it's showing different results. (It is adding the "1" as a string.) And without the spaces, it is returning the property and method names.

Can someone please break down the meaning of the code to me? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't `1` (=one), it's `l` (el)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [for ... in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

> What does the var 1 mean?

Each time you go around the loop, a different property of the object (`document.body`) is assigned to the variable `l` (which is a lowercase `L` not the numeral one).

Replacing the variable name with a string will use the literal value of that string instead of the property name.

> iterating over the array

It isn't an array, it is an object (more specifically an [HTML body element object](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#dom-document-body)).

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks so much. That "1" part was tripping me off big time. :-)